# Use enum like a getter?

Tags: java, enums, syntactic-sugar

I have a util class that keeps track of important system variables:

```
public static final String REQUEST_ADDRESS = "http.request.address";  
public static final String REQUEST_PORT = "http.request.port";

public static final String get(String property) {
    return System.getProperty(property);
}
```

And I can retrieve these values like so:

```
String port = SystemPropertyHelper.get(SystemPropertyHelper.REQUEST_PORT);
```

Is it possible, in Java, to get these like an enum?

```
REQUEST_PORT {
    return System.getProperty("http.request.port");
}

String port = SystemPropertyHelper.REQUEST_PORT;
```

Comment: What's wrong with string constants?

Comment: Wouldn't that prevent a change in that value from being picked up?  (Even if changing such values is an anti-pattern)

Comment: I like to use Interfaces for constants, because you don't have to type `public static final` modifiers. Just think about it. Saving like 2 seconds on constant!

Comment: @IVRAvenger so you want to use enum to store some mutable data?

Answer (score 3):

I'd solve it that way.

```
public static final String REQUEST_PORT = System.getProperty("http.request.port");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
        enum SystemPropertyHelper {
            REQUEST_PORT("http.request.port"), ...;

            private String key;

            Config(String key) {
                this.key = key;
            }

            public String get() {
             return System.getProperty(key);
            }
        }
```

and use it like `SystemPropertyHelper.REQUEST_PORT.get();`

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you could create an `enum` like this, which would give you access to the property name, and the value:

```
public enum SystemPropertyEnum {
    REQUEST_PORT("http.request.port"),
    REQUEST_ADDRESS("http.request.address");

    private String propertyName;
    private String value;

    SystemPropertyEnum(final String propertyName) {
        this.propertyName = propertyName;
        this.value = System.getProperty(propertyName);
    }

    public String getPropertyName() {
        return propertyName;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

However, you could avoid the need to call a getter by just using `public static final String` variables for your properties, as [@halloei](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35225430/2561365) suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can do something like this:

```
public enum Properties {
    REQUEST_PORT("http.request.port"),
    REQUEST_USE_SSL("http.request.ssl");
    // Add others...

    private final String value;

    Properties(String value) {
        this.value = System.getProperty(value);
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

This can be use like:

```
String port = Properties.REQUEST_PORT.getValue();
```